# Swift 2.2: Accessing/Modifying Class Variables from Class Protocol

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, uiview

I've been digging around and can't quite seem to find an answer to this... I am trying to implement something like the simplified protocol setup below.

```
//PROTOCOL SETUP
protocol myProtocol: class {
   var thisVariable: CustomType? {get set}
}

extension myProtocol {
   func doSomeThings() { //IMPLEMENTATION SPOT 1// }
}

extension theClassIAmUsing: myProtocol {
   func doSomeThings() { //IMPLEMENTATION SPOT 2// }
}

//NEW IN SWFIT
extension myProtocol where Self: theClassIAmUsing {
   func doSomeThings() { //IMPLEMENTATION SPOT 3// }
} 

//CLASS:
class theClassIAmUsing: UIView, myProtocol {
   var thisVariable: CustomType? = CustomType() //etc...
   //does not implement doSomeThings() but is available

   init() {
   //some init
   }
}
```

The implementation I am trying to use is performing logic/function based on:

```
self.thisVariable!.element
```

and **IT WORKS!**  but only in **IMPLEMENTATION SPOTS 2 and 3**...

The point of my question is, if I'm subclassing UIView for use around my application, I will need to add an extention of myProtocol "where Self:" is (the next custom class) **EVERY TIME** I create a new subclass....... (yea this cleans up the class definition code section but seems tedious.)

It may be picky, by wouldn't it seem reasonable to be able to access self.thisVariable in an extention of the protocol so that it may be used in all of my subclassed UIViews??

Am I missing something?

The error I get in IMPLEMENTATION SPOT 1 is:

```
warning: could not load any Objective-C class information. 
This will significantly reduce the quality of type information available.
```

Comment: Can't you just do `extension UIView: myProtocol {`?

Comment: If I try to extend UIView: myProtocol it says UIView does not conform to the protocol